# Fast Technician CD (BartPE,Knoppix,Ghost,Gparted)

Tags: boot-cd, ghost

AS the title states im looking for a disk that can meet the following requirements:

- Fast load up time, < 1:30s
- Linux Based
- Gparted
- Drive Detection (Unlike BartPE)
- Norton Ghost
- Possibly Dos (not really needed).
- Automatic drive detection (Unlike BartPE - *Having to plug in devices within pre-boot*)

**Has anyone got any suggestions ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your demands are unrealizable, as:

1. Norton Ghost doesn't exist on Linux
2. Norton Ghost being commercial, that boot CD will require a pirated version
3. Linux doesn't contain DOS, except for some emulators
4. A full-Linux distribution will not boot from a DVD in < 1:30s.
   Even from hard disk it may take a couple of minutes.

For fast boot, and what's more from DVD, you are stuck with a mini-Linux distribution.
You can search your ideal Linux distro on [distrowatch](http://distrowatch.com/).

Or you can [Roll Your Own Linux Distro](http://www.linux.org/news/2008/01/24/0002.html), further explained [here](http://www.informationweek.com/news/software/showArticle.jhtml?articleID=205917063).

In a multi-boot DVD Ghost can be one of the options and Knoppix Slimmed another. There are many tutorials for creating such DVDs, or via utilities such as MagicISO.

Comment: Firstly, Norton ghost is available on linux, see: http://www.symantec.com/themes/theme.jsp?themeid=ghost Secondly, We have a commercial licence for the product, Thirdly, regarding DOS, we would be looking at a Boot manager that can boot DOS or Linux, and regarding the boot time, Knoppix 3.x Slimmed.. boots in under 1:30, Thanks for he link on "Roll your own distro."

Comment: I can't see Linux in System Requirements of Ghost in the link you provided. But see my edit above.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried Parted Magic - http://partedmagic.com/. It includes Gparted, Clonezilla (like Ghost), and a load of other disk tools / utilities (see http://partedmagic.com/programs.html for the full list of programs it includes).

Comment: Unfortunately Ghost is a must :( we already have a server with 4-5 hounded images that we use daily, backups of servers / consoles.

Comment: Okay, it might be stating the obvious, but, why don't you restore your images and remake them with Clonezilla. Also, Ghost is licensed software, so I doubt if there would be a "Technician CD" with Ghost on it - well not legally anyway.

Comment: Thats why im researching our custom built  built CD that would be built onto 10 500GB External HDD's, As its custom built and we have a licence it would be ok to use.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps [Hiren's Boot CD](http://www.hirensbootcd.net/)? It includes a lot of useful stuff, it is Linux and DOS based.

Contains partition manager tools and imaging software for sure, and a lot more...

Comment: When I say Linux based, I mean Linux with the software on that distro, not a mini linux with software bundled outside of the distro, we do use `HBCD` and `UBCD` but we need something different, more specific.

Comment: Can you list your goal in the question? I don't see how a Linux environment (which only takes longer to boot) can be more useful for the tasks that `HBCD` and `UBCD` already offer you.

Answer (score 0):

Go with misterjaytee's suggestion. I use partedmagic to reimage systems to larger drives and to rescue damaged windows systems! A must in your IT toolbox!